# How to loop through a LinkedIn API response?

Tags: php, arrays, linkedin-api

I am retrieving connections via LinkedIn's API.

This is a sample of the response.  All I want to do is loop through this using PHP, accessing first and last names.  Should be simple, but I am stumped.  Thanks.

> stdClass Object ( [_total] => 420 [values] => Array ( [0] => stdClass
>   Object ( [apiStandardProfileRequest] => stdClass Object ( [headers] =>
>   stdClass Object ( [_total] => 1 [values] => Array ( [0] => stdClass
>   Object ( [name] => x-li-auth-token [value] => name:AnUY ) ) ) [url] =>
>   http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/7yw8k_sjqf ) [firstName] => John
>   [headline] => Finance Manager at ABC. [id] => 7yw8k_sjqf [industry] =>
>   Insurance [lastName] => Doe [location] => stdClass Object ( [country]
>   => stdClass Object ( [code] => us ) [name] => Greater Atlanta Area ) [pictureUrl] =>
>   http://m.c.lnkd.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_73E_PMM3nzAIZLG03bHpPRo3qvCwZL_0DhYpPRogIxiFs7jUYPVRGNRGC1mGegyyqdihoC
>   [siteStandardProfileRequest] => stdClass Object ( [url] =>
>   http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=2633833&authType=name&authToken=AnUY&trk=api*a189561*s197687*
>   ) ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [apiStandardProfileRequest] => stdClass
>   Object ( [headers] => stdClass Object ( [_total] => 1 [values] =>
>   Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => x-li-auth-token [value] =>
>   name:tpAo ) ) ) [url] => http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/FW8obZbI8R
>   ) [firstName] => Jeremy [headline] => Owner, BCD [id] => FW8obZbI8R
>   [industry] => Computer Software [lastName] => Doe [location] =>
>   stdClass Object ( [country] => stdClass Object ( [code] => us ) [name]
>   => Greater Chicago Area ) [pictureUrl] => http://m.c.lnkd.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_Lw2NlImcd1e6LmQpL2mIleOMIcf9LeFpbu4IlexHq-R6V2ryWSpZ0HI6LM7rXeaEYf3Gt69H
>   [siteStandardProfileRequest] => stdClass Object ( [url] =>
>   http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=6700159&authType=name&authToken=tpAo&trk=api*a189561*s197687*
>   ) ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [apiStandardProfileRequest] => stdClass
>   Object ( [headers] => stdClass Object ( [_total] => 1 [values] =>
>   Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => x-li-auth-token [value] =>
>   name:eETp ) ) ) [url] => http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/a7-dvlvc7K
>   ) [firstName] => Jane [headline] => Sr. Consultant System Integration
>   at AT&T [id] => a7-dvlvc7K [industry] => Telecommunications [lastName]
>   => Doe [location] => stdClass Object ( [country] => stdClass Object ( [code] => us ) [name] => Greater New York City Area ) [pictureUrl] =>
>   http://m.c.lnkd.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_459zxGU8TBpTZjvisicExTgSSvZCsYXisCGExTR-t1ut5V1_N_6JA37p_Z4gJQqIK653RvmW
>   [siteStandardProfileRequest] => stdClass Object ( [url] =>
>   http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=119413921&authType=name&authToken=eETp&trk=api*a189561*s197687*
>   ) ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [apiStandardProfileRequest] => stdClass
>   Object ( [headers] => stdClass Object ( [_total] => 1 [values] =>
>   Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => x-li-auth-token [value] =>
>   name:HjUG ) ) ) [url] => http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/aie8Zpk9Gm
>   ) [firstName] => John [headline] => Financial Information/Market Data
>   Professional [id] => aie8Zpk9Gm [industry] => Financial Services
>   [lastName] => Smith [location] => stdClass Object ( [country] =>
>   stdClass Object ( [code] => gb ) [name] => Glasgow, United Kingdom )
>   [pictureUrl] =>
>   http://m.c.lnkd.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_N0TLAL3BTlHZCVAbTNTAD03RCjngvsAbCIY-JfOxvg4JldxF9L7MShCp_Avp_ROhKS8LNY
>   [siteStandardProfileRequest] => stdClass Object ( [url] =>
>   http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=1562499&authType=name&authToken=HjUG&trk=api*a189561*s197687*
>   ) ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [apiStandardProfileRequest] => stdClass
>   Object ( [headers] => stdClass Object ( [_total] => 1 [values] =>
>   Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => x-li-auth-token [value] =>
>   name:aZIS ) ) ) [url] => http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/XTGgSuagWI
>   ) [firstName] => Bob [headline] => CEO, Nycomed US at NMO [id] =>
>   XTGgSuagWI [industry] => Pharmaceuticals [lastName] => brown
>   [location] => stdClass Object ( [country] => stdClass Object ( [code]
>   => us ) [name] => Greater New York City Area ) [pictureUrl] => http://m.c.lnkd.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_UciCehxmKngbM15je_qytdVG-zSbJrcje_92S7a-DlsFcA1m6iCGyXsjl-uwsq3ybXXbrd1L
>   [siteStandardProfileRequest] => stdClass Object ( [url] =>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have as the response is an [stdclass](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php#language.types.object.casting) which will have all of its properties public.

This is how you iterate it:

```
$response = $this->getResponseFromLinkedIn();
foreach ($response->values as $value) {
    $firstName = $value->firstName;
    $lastName = $value->lastName;
    // do something with the extracted values!
}
```

Comment: Fantastic.  Works a charm.  Thanks :-)